# RealmSwift limiting and fetching last 30 records into tableview

Tags: swift3, realm

I'm a newbie of using RealmSwift and i'm creating chat like application using swift 3.0 with backend database as RealmSwift. while inserting the chat works good into realm, but the thing when fetch the records

```
let newChat = uiRealm.objects(Chats.self).filter(
    "(from_id == \(signUser!.user_id) 
         OR from_id == \(selectedList.user_id))
         AND (to_id == \(signUser!.user_id) 
         OR to_id == \(selectedList.user_id))"
).sorted(byProperty: "id", ascending: true)
```

i don't know how to limit the last 30 records for the chat conversation. In the above code i just fetch the records from "Chat" table with filtering the chat as "SIGNED USERID AND TO USERID". and also if i list all the records(like more than 150 chat conversation) for the particular  chat, then scrolling up the records from tableview got stuck up or hang for a while. So please give some idea about how to limit last 30 records and stop hanging the tableview. Thanks in advance

Comment: have you read https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#limiting-results ?

Comment: yeah i read that, actually while limiting if i have total 60 records then i have limit last 30 means from 31st record to 60th record. the problem is how to give the initial value because i knew the last record is 60

Answer (score 1):

Like I wrote [in the Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#limiting-results), because Realm `Results` objects are lazily-loaded, it doesn't matter if you query for all of the objects and then simply load the ones you need.

If you want to line it up to a table view, you could create an auxiliary method that maps the last 30 results to a 0-30 index range, which would be easier to then pass straight to the table view's data source:

```
func chat(atIndex index: Integer) -> Chats {
   let mappedIndex = (newChat.count - 30) + index
   return newChat[mappedIndex]
}
```

If you've already successfully queried and started accessing these objects (i.e. the query itself didn't hang), I'm not sure why the table view would hang after the fact. You could try running the Time Profiler in [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/) to track down exactly what's causing the main thread to be blocked.